# CSS Animation from height 100% to 0% fadeOut

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

```js
const blackBg = document.getElementById("content__blackbg-id");

function displayBlock(){

    blackBg.style.animation ="fadein 2s";
    blackBg.style.height = "100%";

}

function displayNone(){

    
    blackBg.style.animation = ""
    blackBg.style.animation ="fadeout 2s";
    blackBg.style.height = "";

}

const sideBar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");

function openNav() {
    sideBar.style.width = "25%";
    displayBlock();
}

function closeNav() {
    sideBar.style.width = "0%";
    displayNone();
}
```

```css
.contenedor{
        display:grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
}


/*MAIN MENU*/

.main-menu{
        padding: 2rem;
        grid-row: 2 / 3;
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
        position: sticky;
        top:0%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        background:linear-gradient(to right, #19BAF6, #10DCEC , #1BDFDF, #17E7BE, #00FFD4);
}


/* COLLAPSIBLE MENU */

.sidebar{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 100%;
        width: 0%;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        transition: .5s;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 10px 0px 20px #000;
}


.sidebar__closebtn{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0rem;
        right: 0rem;
        font-size: 4rem;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 2rem;
        z-index: 2;
}



@keyframes fadein{
        from{
                opacity: 0;
        }
        to{
                opacity: 1;
        }
}

@keyframes fadeout{
        from{
                opacity: 1;
        }
        to{
                opacity: 0;
        }
}

.content__blackbg{
        grid-row: 1 / 5;
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        background: #0008;
        display: block;
        height: 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <nav class="main-menu">
            <ul class="main-menu__ul">
                <li class="main-menu__li"><a class="main-menu__a" href="#" onclick="openNav()">TU CUENTA &#9776;</li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
            <a href="#" class="sidebar__closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        </div>
        <div id = "content__blackbg-id" class="content__blackbg">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a div which  has `height:0%;`. When clicking on a button the div changes to height 100% with an Animation of fading. I made it work for the height from 0% to 100% but when i click again on the same button the div must change to height 0% and with an Animation of fadeout. This animation from height 100% to 0% doesnt work.

**This is the css, with the style of the Div and the animations**

```
.content__blackbg{
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #0008;
    display: block;
    height: 0%;
}


@keyframes fadein{
    from{
            opacity: 0;
    }
    to{
            opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeout{
    from{
            opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
            opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Now with Javascript i'm adding the change to the height and the Animations to the Div

```
const blackBg = document.getElementById("content__blackbg-id");

*When clicking on the button*

blackBg.style.animation ="fadein 2s";
blackBg.style.height = "100%";

*When clicking again*

blackBg.style.animation = ""
blackBg.style.animation ="fadeout 2s";
blackBg.style.height = "";
```

Comment: Could you post complete snippet?

Comment: Try changing this `blackBg.style.height = "";` to `blackBg.style.height = "0%";`

Comment: @cse_vikashgupta I've added a code snippet.

Comment: @vio This doesn't work

Comment: I think this line `blackBg.style.animation = ""` is causing the problem. Why do you have this line when you are already changing the animation using another line. Also, maybe you have to `;` at the end of this line.

Comment: @vio It doesn't matter, the final result will always be `blackBg.style.animation = "fadeout"`. Even deleting this line `blackBg.style.animation = ""` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this by using transitions instead of keyframes. The problem with using keyframes is they are for defining an animation but not a state change. What you are seeing is the animation happening, but the CSS properties are adjusted for only the duration of the animation.

Edit: You posted some more code after I created this, but you should be able to apply this towards your code regardless.

```js
const blackBg = document.getElementById("content__blackbg-id");
const animationTrigger = document.getElementById("animationTrigger");

let blackBgVisible = true;

animationTrigger.onclick = event => {
  if (blackBgVisible) {
    runFadeOut();
  } else {
    runFadeIn();
  }
  blackBgVisible = !blackBgVisible;
};

function runFadeIn() {
  blackBg.classList.replace("fadeOut", "fadeIn");
}

function runFadeOut() {
  blackBg.classList.replace("fadeIn", "fadeOut");
}
```

```css
.content__blackbg {
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #0008;
  display: block;
}

.fadeIn {
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.fadeOut {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="content__blackbg-id" class="content__blackbg fadeIn">Placeholder</div>
<div align="center">
  <button id="animationTrigger">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but i'm using Animations because with Transitions it's visible how the element changes its height value. Would it be possible to show only the fade effect?

Comment: Yep, you can do that by just removing "height" from the properties listed in transition. I just edited my post with that change. Before it was `transition: height 2s, opacity 2s`.

Comment: so for the fadeIn the transition works perfectly but for the fadeOut only works if i use the `transition: height 2s, opacity 2s;`. If i remove the `Height: 2s;` or replace it by `background: 2s;` it's again a fast change without transitions.